# No qualifying bean of type 'com.assessment.bankSimulation.entity.BankAccount' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-bean

So I'm Trying to make a demo banking app using multithreading. I have 2 classes BankAccount and Customer. I have annotated them both with @Component
Here is the exception im facing.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.assessment.b`enter code here`ankSimulation.entity.BankAccount' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1178)
    at com.assessment.bankSimulation.BankSimulationApplication.main(BankSimulationApplication.java:17)
```

I have annotated them both with @Component but spring is saying *No qualifying bean for this type available*. I have tried @ComponentScan Annotation as well till of no Use.

**BankAccount**

```
@Component
public class BankAccount {
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public BankAccount(BigDecimal initialAmount) {
        this.balance = initialAmount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deposit(BigDecimal amount) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            balance = balance.add(amount);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup() + "deposited " + amount + "at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void withDraw(BigDecimal amount) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (balance.compareTo(amount) >= 0) {
                balance = balance.subtract(amount);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "withdrew " + amount + "at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            } else {
                throw new InsufficientBalanceException(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "cant withdraw " + amount + "due to insufficient balance");
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();

        }
    }
}
```

It gave an error to define a bean for "java.math.Bigdecimal" as well by using @ComponentScan I was able to resolve that issue.

**Main**

```
@ComponentScan({"java.math.BigDecimal"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class BankSimulationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(BankSimulationApplication.class, args);

        BankAccount bankAccount = context.getBean(BankAccount.class);
        Customer firstCustomer = context.getBean(Customer.class);
        Customer secondCustomer = context.getBean(Customer.class);
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(firstCustomer);
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(secondCustomer);
        firstThread.start();
        secondThread.start();
        try {
            firstThread.join();
            secondThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Total Balance = " + bankAccount.getBalance());
    }

}
```

I have tried @EnableComponentScan annotation as well but I'm still unable to get my head around this.

Comment: Read the documentation for `@ComponentScan`. Can you think of why using it the way you have would stop your `BankAccount` component from being found?

Comment: I guess its because I'm creating a constructor for BankAccount so spring is getting confused which one I want @tgdavies

Comment: "Either basePackageClasses() or basePackages() (or its alias value()) may be specified to define specific packages to scan." https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html Do you think that `@ComponentScan({"java.math.BigDecimal"})` will scan `com.assessment.bankSimulation.entity`?

Comment: Hi I guess you missed the part where I said **It gave an error to define a bean for "java.math.Bigdecimal"** @tgdavies

Comment: No, I didn't miss that. You want to define several beans, in different packages (defining a bean for `BigDecimal` doesn't really make sense, but that's another question)

Comment: If the point of the exercise if learning about multithreading I wouldn't use Spring at all.